# Selenium, can't locate an element

Tags: java, selenium

`<div class="select-organization"><a organization-activate="1">Suresh</a></div>`

[image: ElementCode[1]]

Using selenium, I'm trying to locate this element, I've tried CSS, XPath, link text but nothing helps

Comment: show us the html text of element or url

Comment: Please read before asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you inspect that element and provide html code

Comment: inspect the full code because we can't say that the element is on frame

Answer (score 0):

Please try this locater :- `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Suresh"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below CSS Selector.

```
.select-organization > a:nth-child(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the element is in a list or in select tag ?  Then try with List or can handle it by creating an object of Select. Might this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the element located within an iframe? You will need to switch to an iframe before you can locate elements within it.
driver.switchTo().frame("frameid"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[./text='Suresh']));

Answer (score -1):

Use the following xpath to match with inner html text of anchor tag:

```
//div[contains(@class,'select-organization')]//text()[contains(., 'Suresh')]
```

- contains is a function that operates on a string. Here it is passed an individual text node (.)

Comment: woking in firepath of my mozzilla, sorry couldn't help

Comment: Maybe issue with time, use some explicit wait

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select-organization']//a"));
```

Comment: Didn't work, ERR: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='select-organization']//a"}

Comment: Are you sure, Web driver is looking on same page where this elements are located,

Comment: I'm pretty sure